# How to call a html page and make it as pop up window in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, popup, popupwindow

how to call a html page as a pop up window using pure/native JavaScript? Sorry, I'm not so good in Javascript. Please help me. Thank you

How can I add your given script into my script?

Here's my script:

```
 function scanLapVerification() {
 msgbox("sendRequest: scanLapVerification");
 chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tabLapVerification, { method: "scanLapVerification" },
    function (response) {
        msgbox("receiveResponse: scanLapVerification " + jsonToString(response, "JSON"));
        // maintaining state in the background
        if (response.data.content == "address_check") {
            //open google maps with request for contact address
             var gmaps;
                if (confirm("Do you want to proceed on Google Maps and search for Contact Address?") == true) {
                gmaps = tabCreate("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + encodeURIComponent(response.data.contact_address));
            } else {
                gmaps = "You Cancel!";
            }
            document.getElementById("maps").innerText = gmaps;
        }
    }
);   
}
```

Comment: Have a look here and choose a popup you like -- http://www.sitepoint.com/14-jquery-modal-dialog-boxes/  -- You may need to use IFRAME to display your html page but try both ways and see what works.

Comment: @Tasos but I need pure/native javascript and I dont know how to convert the jquery into native javascript :(

Comment: Here as some examples with JQM --- http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-mobile.html

Comment: @Tasos the examples are all jquery, and i dont know how to convert it to native/pure javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the answer, I just put this little script

```
popupWindow = window.open('/test.htm', 'name', 'width=700,height=350');
popupWindow.focus();
```