# Is this possible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modalviewcontroller, popupwindow

My question is, if I open a particular web site (HTML website), another Particular web site should be popped up in that same website. But the popup shouldn't come in a new window or another window.

I have tried using HTML, Java Script, J query and even Modal view. But I couldn't find a solution for this. Can anyone please suggest me whether is this possible or not?

If so possible, Can u please suggest that way with an example?

And in that particular web site in code level, they gave same origin. So I can’t use i frame, object and embedded.So, please don’t say these 3 options [i frame, object, embedded].

It will be so helpful, if I get a solution as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance.
Thanks & Regards,
Hariharan

Comment: iframe http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp The <iframe> tag specifies an inline frame.

An inline frame is used to embed another document within the current HTML document.

Comment: `<iframe src="http://www.theotherwebsite.com" width="640" height="480"></iframe>`

Comment: Note, not all websites (such as Google) allow themselves to be displayed in a frame via the [`x-frame-options` response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)

Comment: I hope this link will help you. 
check this 

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987938/how-to-call-a-html-page-and-make-it-as-pop-up-window-in-javascript

Comment: Hi Saj,In code level in that particular web site, they gave same origin. So I can’t use iframe, object, embedded

Answer (score 1):

maybe **[fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)** can help you to create pop up from other page in same window.

Answer (score 0):

May be an iframe is what you want. 
Check this out [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe)

Comment: In code level in that particular web site, they gave same origin. So I can’t use iframe, object, embedded

Answer (score 0):

use iframe
        `<iframe src="http://getbootstrap.com/"></iframe>`

Comment: In code level in that particular web site, they gave same origin. So I can’t use iframe, object, embedded